# Missing context menu in VS2013 ultimate "Add Controller", "Add View"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am assuming this is due to an error I am receiving when my project loads.

**The 'ScaffoldingVsPackage' package did not load correctly**

I really have no idea what is going on. I just installed this and I know scaffolding goes hand in hand with views and controllers. This is the log I am getting. Can anyone help out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but my error is related to scaffolding item.

I need to uninstall visual studio and went through all the related folders, registry and re-install visual studio in order to make it work!

Folders that I checked:

%App Data%
%Program Data%
%Program Files%
Windows
basically I searched anything that has "visual studio" & "scaffolding" in folders & registry, delete all and restart the PC before I install the visual studio again!

Hope that help :)